# ANSI C used to control external application?

Tags: c, windows, keyboard, mouse, ui-automation

In windows 10, I have an ANSI C console program running and another program running (for example notepad.exe) and I want the C program to write text to the notepad program, is this possible? The C program would need to find and select the notepad program before sending text.

I used notepad as a common example but in reality the this program is a matlab console, and I can't use the matlab engine to push the command.

Comment: You would probably need not an "ANSI C console program", but some Windows API based one. Which knows how to send messages between windows and such.

Comment: *"I can't use the matlab engine to push the command."* so you basically want to "hack" Matlab from a different process. That seems... highly impractical to say the least. It'd really be easier to write a keyboard emulator at that point.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) (which is just called C) or [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in C? Why C? Why not something more Windows native like C# or PowerShell, if not something simple like Python?

Comment: The real problem I am trying to solve is how to send a non-blocking command to matlab from ANSI C.  My C program opens a matlab command window then continuously pumps real-time data to matlab via the matlab engine.  The command I need to send is to run a script which processes the data on the matlab side.  So currently to make this work I start the C program then once the matlab command window is open I must manually type script name in matlab for it to run.  I'm stuck with C rather than C++ because of legacy C libraries.

Comment: C++ can use C libraries, as can anything that uses [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface), which includes a whole ton of scripting languages.

Comment: Please add new information by [edit]ing your question, not here in the comments. This is not a forum or a messenger, here are *comments*.

Comment: It is possible, definitively. As @EugeneSh. said, you need to write a program using the Windows API. You might like to look at AutoIt that does exactly what you want.